# Axios with random API

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to use random API in my application using axios and I get error that "TypeError: randomData.map is not a function". Maybe someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

    const [randomData, setRandomDate] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
            .then(res => {
                console.log('Getting from: ', res.data)
                setRandomDate(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])

    const arr = randomData.map((data, index) => {
        return (
            <p>{data}</p>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Learning React:</h1>
            {arr}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Apparently, `res.data` is not an array. What does your console.log statement say? From peeking at `randomuser.me/api`, I'm guessing you need `res.data.results`

Comment: It's telling you that what you're calling `.map()` on isn't an array.  So when you debug, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that randomuser api returns an object

```
{
info: ...,
results: [{}]
}
```

so when you setRandomData to just `res.data`, you are assigning an object to your state, and `map` is not part of an object prototype.

What you need to do is to replace `setRandomDate(res.data)` with `setRandomDate(res.data.results)` and now you will be able to map that array.

like

```
  const arr = randomData.map((data, index) => {
      return (
          <p>{data.email}</p>
      )
  })
```